# a strange name next to the webapp name shown in eclipse server tab

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, wildfly

My pom is as follow:

```
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>net.codejava</groupId>
  <artifactId>EhrmsWs</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
```

and in eclipse,web project settings, context root is
EhrmsWs

but when I add this webapp to wildfly runtime, there is a name
MyWebsite-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

1. where does this name come from and what does it represents?

[image]

2. my context root is still
   http://127.0.0.1:8080/EhrmsWs
   ?
3. the application is a simple web service example, I access using postman, request is
   http://127.0.0.1:8080/EhrmsWs/rest/products/
   but it returns 404 - Not Found, why?

the web.xml setting is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>EhrmsWs</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>net.codejava.ws</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

the service class is as follow:

```
package net.codejava.ws;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/products")
public class ProductResource {
    private ProductDAO dao = ProductDAO.getInstance();
    
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response list() {
        List<Product> listProducts = dao.listAll();
         
        if (listProducts.isEmpty()) {
            return Response.noContent().build();
        }
         
        return Response.ok(listProducts).build();
    }
    //.....
}
```

[Edit on 20220816]

Now the request
http://localhost:8080/EhrmsWs/rest/products
can pass to resource ProductResource.java, but I write a similar resource TrainingHist.java with similar method as follow:

```
package net.codejava.ws;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/trainingHist")
public class TrainingHistResource {
    private TrainingHistDAO dao = TrainingHistDAO.getInstance();
    
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response list() {
        List<TrainingHist> listTrainingHists = dao.listAll();
         
        if (listTrainingHists.isEmpty()) {
            return Response.noContent().build();
        }
         
        return Response.ok(listTrainingHists).build();
    }
}
```

then I send the get request
http://localhost:8080/EhrmsWs/rest/trainingHist

but it returns 404 not found, why?

Comment: Try looking for that string (MyWebsite) in all the project files. You can use the "Find in files" of Eclipse, or the method you prefer

Comment: I search and find the word "MyWebsite" appear in EhrmsWs/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component, then I change all occurence of "MyWebsite" to "EhrmsWs", then run maven clean install, but after that, when start server, I still see " WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "MyWebsite-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "MyWebsite-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")", although in server tab, the "MyWebsite" word is disappeared.

Comment: I'm not used to work with .wars nor wildfly. But then I suggest also checking for files or directories with that name. If there is none left, maybe some cache somewhere? No idea from here, sorry